# How to separate babel chunks when build npm package?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs

I'm making a ui kit for an application that connects as a separate module. I want to be able to do imports in ES6. Like this

```
import { Button } from '@app/ui-kit'
```

Now it works, but i pull it all up js code to result bundle. The package is divided into commonjs and es6 modules.
package.json:

```
"main": "index.js",
"module": "./dist/es6/index.js",
"jsnext:main": "./dist/es6/index.js",
"types": "./src/index.ts",
```

Imports in dist/es6

```
export * from './GlobalStyle';
export * from './Loader';
export * from './Theme';
export * from './Button';
```